# PyQt QFrame border set with stylesheet ignored if use selector with custom property

Tags: python-2.7, css-selectors, pyqt4

In python 2.7 with PyQt 4.7 I develop a composite widget with this structure:

- InfoPanel (QFrame with custom property CssStyle)

  - OuterPanel (QFrame)

    - InnerPanel (QFrame)

      - Title (QLabel)
      - line (Line)
      - Description (QLabel)

This is the stylesheet I apply:

```
InfoPanel {
    border: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
InfoPanel[CssStyle=""] #OuterPanel {
    background-color: blue;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    border-width: 40px 96px 10px 96px;
}
InfoPanel[CssStyle="HeaderSize"] #OuterPanel {
    background-color: blue;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 10px 96px 0px 96px;
}
InfoPanel[CssStyle=""] #Title {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 24pt;
}
InfoPanel[CssStyle=""] #Description {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
InfoPanel[CssStyle="HeaderSize"] #Title {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
InfoPanel[CssStyle="HeaderSize"] #Description {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 8pt;
}
```

This is the python method in the InfoPanel widget that show itself setting the custom property:

```
def showInfo(css_style='') {
    self.setVisible(True)
    self.setProperty('CssStyle', css_style)
    self.style().unpolish(self)
    self.style().polish(self)
    self.update()
    self.InnerPanel.style().unpolish(self.InnerPanel)
    self.InnerPanel.style().polish(self.InnerPanel)
    self.InnerPanel.update()
    self.OuterPanel.style().unpolish(self.OuterPanel)
    self.OuterPanel.style().polish(self.OuterPanel)
    self.OuterPanel.update()
    self.Title.style().unpolish(self.Title)
    self.Title.style().polish(self.Title)
    self.Title.update()
    self.line.style().unpolish(self.line)
    self.line.style().polish(self.line)
    self.line.update()
    self.Description.style().unpolish(self.Description)
    self.Description.style().polish(self.Description)
    self.Description.update()
}
```

If I run **showInfo()** I can see the green border, if I run **showInfo('HeaderSize')** I can see the red border; but anyway the children widgets ignore the border, I can see the Title widget positioned over the border in the top left corner!

Is this a bug or am I wrong?
Anyone can help me?

Comment: I'm still in trouble with this strange bug...
I think there is no solution so I will duplicate the widget in two simpler widgets to get the funcionality I can't obtain using stylesheet on a single widget.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you!

```
self.FRAME_main = CustomQFrame(self);
self.FRAME_main.setGeometry(10, 40, self.GRAPH_W-20, self.GRAPH_H-160);
self.FRAME_main._GRAPH_SIZE = [ self.GRAPH_W, self.GRAPH_H ];
self.FRAME_main.setFrameStyle(QFrame.NoFrame);
#self.FRAME_main.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel);
self.FRAME_main.setStyleSheet('QFrame { background-color: #333; }');
#self.FRAME_main.hide();

_info_W = 300;
_info_H = 40;
_info_style = """
    QTextEdit{  

        background-color: #000; color: #fff; padding: 0px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        background-color: blue;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: red;
        border-width: 4px 4px 4px 4px;

    }"""

self.FRAME_main.current_curency_info = QTextEdit("innerText", self.FRAME_main);
self.FRAME_main.current_curency_info.setGeometry((self.GRAPH_W/2)-(_info_W/2), 5, _info_W, _info_H);
self.FRAME_main.current_curency_info.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop|Qt.AlignLeft);
self.FRAME_main.current_curency_info.setStyleSheet(_info_style);
self.FRAME_main.current_curency_info.setEnabled(True);
self.FRAME_main.current_curency_info.setReadOnly(True);
#self.FRAME_main.current_curency_info.setOpenExternalLinks(True);
self.FRAME_main.current_curency_info.show();
```

It was sample of prog.

```
_info_style = """
    QTextEdit{  

        background-color: #000; color: #fff; padding: 0px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        background-color: blue;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: red;
        border-width: 4px 4px 4px 4px;

    }"""

self.FRAME_main.current_curency_info.setStyleSheet(_info_style);
```